# How to Convert HTML Table to JSON in PHP

Tags: php, html, json, parsing, domdocument

I am trying to convert some html into an array then into a json string.

I am developing based on this reference: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1074174/Simple-Way-to-Convert-HTML-Table-Data-into-PHP-Arr

This is the basic table/html from which I want to convert it to JSON.

```
<table class="table-list table table-responsive table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="coll-1 name">name</th>
        <th class="coll-2">height</th>
        <th class="coll-3">weight</th>
        <th class="coll-date">date</th>
        <th class="coll-4"><span class="info">info</span></th>
        <th class="coll-5">country</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td class="coll-1 name">
        <a href="/username/Jhon Doe/" class="icon"><i class="flaticon-user"></i></a>
        <a href="/username/Jhon Doe/">Jhon Doe</a>
    </td>
    <td class="coll-2 height">45</td>
    <td class="coll-3 weight">50</td>
    <td class="coll-date">9am May. 16th</td>
    <td class="coll-4 size mob-info">abcd</td>
    <td class="coll-5 country"><a href="/country/CA/">CA</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="coll-1 name">
        <a href="/username/Kasim Shk/" class="icon"><i class="flaticon-user"></i></a>
        <a href="/username/Kasim Shk/">Kasim Shk</a>
    </td>
    <td class="coll-2 height">33</td>
    <td class="coll-3 weight">54</td>
    <td class="coll-date">Mar. 14th '18</td>
    <td class="coll-4 size mob-info">ijkl</td>
    <td class="coll-5 country"><a href="/country/UAE/">UAE</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

---

I want json output like this:

```
[
    {   
        "user_link": "/username/Jhon Doe/",
        "name": "Jhon Doe",
        "height": "45",
        "weight": "50",
        "date": "Apr. 01st '18",
        "info": "abcd",
        "country": "CA"
    },
    {   
        "user_link": "/username/Kasim Shk/",
        "name": "Kasim Shk",
        "height": "33",
        "weight": "54",
        "date": "Mar. 14th '18",
        "info": "ijkl",
        "country": "UAE"
    }
]
```

---

This is what I was trying in PHP :(

However, this is not able to fetch user's link and the name is not proper in JSON.

(HTML Table same as above @ http://rudraproduction.in/htmltable.php)

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");                                                                            
header('Content-Type: application/json');
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
$time_start = microtime(true);

$All = [];

$link       = 'http://rudraproduction.in/htmltable.php';
$jsonData   = file_get_contents($link);

//echo $jsonData;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($jsonData);

$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
$tr     = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tr'); 

foreach ($tr as $element1) {        
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($element1); $i++) {

        //Not able to fetch the user's link :(

        $link       = $element1->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('a');    // To fetch user link
        $name       = $element1->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0)->textContent;                  // To fetch name
        $height     = $element1->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(1)->textContent;                  // To fetch height
        $weight     = $element1->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(2)->textContent;                  // To fetch weight
        $date       = $element1->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(3)->textContent;                  // To fetch date
        $info       = $element1->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(4)->textContent;                  // To fetch info
        $country    = $element1->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(5)->textContent;                  // To fetch country

        array_push($All, array(
            "user_link" => $link,
            "name"      => $name,
            "height"    => $height,
            "weight"    => $weight,
            "date"      => $date,
            "info"      => $info,
            "country"   => $country
        ));
    }
}

echo json_encode($All, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

---

Output of my PHP code is:

```
[
    {
        "user_link": "http:\/\/rudraproduction.in\/htmltable.php",
        "name": null,
        "height": null,
        "weight": null,
        "date": null,
        "info": null,
        "country": null
    },
    {
        "user_link": "http:\/\/rudraproduction.in\/htmltable.php",
        "name": "\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\tJhon Doe\r\n\t",
        "height": "45",
        "weight": "50",
        "date": "9am May. 16th",
        "info": "abcd",
        "country": "CA"
    },
    {
        "user_link": "http:\/\/rudraproduction.in\/htmltable.php",
        "name": "\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\tKasim Shk\r\n\t",
        "height": "33",
        "weight": "54",
        "date": "Mar. 14th '18",
        "info": "ijkl",
        "country": "UAE"
    }
]
```

Comment: The link you provided shows a means of turning the table into array data, which will be an important first step. Where did you get with that and where did you run into trouble?

Comment: When your have your array using the code that you've linked to, pass it to `json_encode()` and you're done.

Comment: Hello, @mickmackusa please do help me to get the valid output as I want :( I had posted my PHP code and output of that, please do check it & assist me.

Comment: @ChauhanAjay, mickmackusa is currently prevented from communicating on Stack Overflow and will not be able to interact here for 30 days. They've asked me to tell you that they've "been naughty and can't respond." However, they obviously cared significantly about getting you some help and asked that your question be edited and the answer below posted. I have no further information as to the full situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer to use `XPath` with `DomDocument` because of utility/ease of the syntax.  By targeting the only the `<tr>` elements inside the `<tbody>` tag, you can access all required data.

With the exception of the `href` value, the final "all-letters" substring in each `<td>` class value represents your desired key for the associated value.  For this I am using `preg_match()` to extract the final "word" in the class attribute.

When the `$key` is `name`, the `href` attribute value must be stored with the hardcode key: `user_link`.

Your sample date values require some preparation to yield the desired format.  As your input data varies, you may need to modify the regular expression to allow `strtotime()` to properly handle the date expression.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/nHKef))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<table class="table-list table table-responsive table-striped" border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="coll-1 name">name</th>
        <th class="coll-2">height</th>
        <th class="coll-3">weight</th>
        <th class="coll-date">date</th>
        <th class="coll-4"><span class="info">info</span></th>
        <th class="coll-5">country</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td class="coll-1 name">
        <a href="/username/Jhon Doe/" class="icon"><i class="flaticon-user"></i></a>
        <a href="/username/Jhon Doe/">Jhon Doe</a>
    </td>
    <td class="coll-2 height">45</td>
    <td class="coll-3 weight">50</td>
    <td class="coll-date">9am May. 16th</td>
    <td class="coll-4 size mob-info">abcd</td>
    <td class="coll-5 country"><a href="/country/CA/">CA</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="coll-1 name">
        <a href="/username/Kasim Shk/" class="icon"><i class="flaticon-user"></i></a>
        <a href="/username/Kasim Shk/">Kasim Shk</a>
    </td>
    <td class="coll-2 height">33</td>
    <td class="coll-3 weight">54</td>
    <td class="coll-date">Mar. 14th '18</td>
    <td class="coll-4 size mob-info">ijkl</td>
    <td class="coll-5 country"><a href="/country/UAE/">UAE</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//tbody/tr') as $tr) {
    $tmp = []; // reset the temporary array so previous entries are removed
    foreach ($xpath->query("td[@class]", $tr) as $td) {
        $key = preg_match('~[a-z]+$~', $td->getAttribute('class'), $out) ? $out[0] : 'no_class';
        if ($key === "name") {
            $tmp['user_link'] = $xpath->query("a[@class = 'icon']", $td)[0]->getAttribute('href');
        }
        $tmp[$key] = trim($td->textContent);
    }
    $tmp['date'] = date("M. dS 'y", strtotime(preg_replace('~\.|\d+[ap]m *~', '', $tmp['date'])));
    $result[] = $tmp;
}
var_export($result);
echo "\n----\n";
echo json_encode($result);
```

Output: (as multidim array, then json encoded string)

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'user_link' => '/username/Jhon Doe/',
    'name' => 'Jhon Doe',
    'height' => '45',
    'weight' => '50',
    'date' => 'May. 16th \'18',
    'info' => 'abcd',
    'country' => 'CA',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'user_link' => '/username/Kasim Shk/',
    'name' => 'Kasim Shk',
    'height' => '33',
    'weight' => '54',
    'date' => 'Jan. 01st \'70',
    'info' => 'ijkl',
    'country' => 'UAE',
  ),
)
----
[{"user_link":"\/username\/Jhon Doe\/","name":"Jhon Doe","height":"45","weight":"50","date":"May. 16th '18","info":"abcd","country":"CA"},{"user_link":"\/username\/Kasim Shk\/","name":"Kasim Shk","height":"33","weight":"54","date":"Jan. 01st '70","info":"ijkl","country":"UAE"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

consider https://github.com/bakame-php/html-table

I found that this worked better than rolling my own.